# Programmatically change system Visual Effect

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, mfc

I need a couple of tips for some changes I need to make in a project developed in C ++ (with MFC); in particular, I would like to change some of the visual effects settings of Windows 10:

- Is it possible to programmatically deactivate the "Animate controls and elements inside windows" option, available under "System Properties-> Advanced-> Performance-> Settings-> Visual Effects"?

[image]

- Can I change this option only for my application, and not globally at system level?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable "animate controls and elements inside windows" by setting `SPI_SETCLIENTAREAANIMATION`.

> **SPI_SETCLIENTAREAANIMATION**: Turns client area animations on or off. The pvParam parameter is a BOOL variable. Set pvParam to TRUE to
>   enable animations and other transient effects in the client area, or
>   FALSE to disable them. Display features such as flashing, blinking,
>   flickering, and moving content can cause seizures in users with
>   photo-sensitive epilepsy. This flag enables you to enable or disable
>   all such animations.
>
> Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP/2000:  This parameter is not
>   supported.

Then you use [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) to make it effective.

Code:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCLIENTAREAANIMATION, 0, (PVOID)FALSE, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

**Note:**

This function is intended for use with applications that allow the user to customize the environment.

So you cannot change this option only for your application.